# How to disable log zip in apache2

Tags: apache2

How to disable log access/error zip in **apache2** ?

Comment: What an eloquent way to ask a question... Why do you repeat the same sentence 4 times? Do you think that enhances your chance to get a reply? _Shaking my head..._

Comment: Apart from that: the apache http server does _not_ compress log files by itself. You probably have some other tool doing that. Most likely that is `logrotate` which can be configured.

Comment: How disable??
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
 daily
 missingok
 rotate 14
 compress
 delaycompress
 notifempty
 create 640 root adm
 sharedscripts
 postrotate
                if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
                fi;
 endscript
 prerotate
  if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
   run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
  fi; \
 endscript
}

Comment: No idea what you want to say with that comment. I think it is time that you think a bit about basic rules in human communication. If _you_ want something from us, then it is in _your_ interest to write in such a manner that things are easy to understand for us. Just dumping fragments before our feet as you currently do and expect anything to happen is a pretty silly thing to do. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
daily
missingok
rotate 14
compress
delaycompress
notifempty
create 640 root adm
sharedscripts
postrotate
            if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
            fi;
endscript
prerotate
    if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
    fi; \
endscript
```

}

Comment: how disable log zip ?